# ORA-26781 Nested table not supported error -- Occurring only in Oracle 19.10

Tags: oracle, nested-table

I have a table (**trn_aplctn**) with one of the column(**clnt**) as nested table type. This nested table column itself has one of its column(**clnt_prgm**) as nested table type.

Here is the sample code snippet.

```
CREATE TYPE prgm_typ AS OBJECT (  
    prgm_id number(30),
    prg_type VARCHAR2(18),
    prg_flag VARCHAR2(100),
    active        CHAR(1)
);
/
CREATE TYPE prgm_tab_typ IS TABLE OF prgm_typ;
/

CREATE TYPE clnt_typ AS OBJECT ( 
    clnt_id     NUMBER (30),    
    active        CHAR(1),  
    clnt_prgm prgm_tab_typ);
/
CREATE TYPE clnt_tab_typ IS TABLE OF clnt_typ; 
/

CREATE TABLE trn_aplctn
(   
    aplctn_id      Number(30) NOT NULL,
    aplctn_idntfr    VARCHAR2 (64) ,    
    active       CHAR (1 BYTE) DEFAULT 'A' ,    
    clnt clnt_tab_typ
) 
NESTED TABLE clnt STORE AS clnt_tbl
        (
        NESTED TABLE clnt_prgm STORE AS clnt_prgm_tbl 
    );
```

I have been inserting rows in trn_aplctn table and its nested column **Clnt**, **clnt_prgm** without any issues so far. After the latest DB upgrade to 19.10, the insert to the second nested column **clnt_prgm** is not working and i keep getting error as "ORA-26781 Nested table not supported error". Please find below sample insert and update that i use to insert rows in these columns

```
INSERT INTO trn_aplctn ( aplctn_id,aplctn_idntfr,active )
VALUES(123,'APP12345','A');
```

/**Below update to first level of nested column works in both 19.10 and 19.3**/

```
UPDATE trn_aplctn SET clnt = clnt_tab_typ(clnt_typ(100,'A',NULL))
                       WHERE aplctn_idntfr  = 'APP12345'                        
                        AND active      = 'A';
```

/**Below update to second level of nested column works fine in 19.3 but fails in 19.10 with the below error**/

```
 UPDATE TABLE (SELECT clnt FROM trn_aplctn WHERE  aplctn_idntfr = 'APP12345'
  AND active       = 'A')
 SET clnt_prgm =  prgm_tab_typ ( prgm_typ(1000,'NC',1,'A' ))
 where clnt_id   = 100
 AND active        = 'A';
```

26781: Nested table not supported

I also tried to initialize the second level nested column before insert, but it wont allow me to initialize the object itself.

/***Below works fine 19.3 but error during initializing in 19.10

```
UPDATE table ---error 26781: Nested table not supported 
         ( 
                SELECT clnt 
                FROM   trn_aplctn 
                WHERE  aplctn_idntfr = 'APP12345'                       
                AND active      = 'A' ) 
  SET    clnt_prgm = new prgm_tab_typ() 
  WHERE  clnt_id = 100 
  AND    active    = 'A'; 



INSERT INTO TABLE( SELECT clnt_prgm FROM TABLE(SELECT clnt FROM trn_aplctn WHERE  aplctn_idntfr = 'APP12345'
   AND active       = 'A' ) WHERE clnt_id =100 )
 ( prgm_id,prg_type, prg_flag,active )
 VALUES(1000,'NC',1,'A');
```

Has anyone faced this issue in 19.10 version. Same code works fine in 19.3 and throws error in 19.10. Can someone please help me what's really happening.

Answer (score 0):

Was this issue sorted out? One workaround is to disable supplemental logging at table level but it is not an ideal solution.
Thanks
Anil

Comment: looks like a comment